# DBUnit error - missing one the following beans: [dbUnitDatabaseConnection, dataSource]

Tags: java, spring, datasource, dbunit

I'm trying to use DBUnit with multiple databases loading from different configuration files (different projects).

In my Foo @Configuration file I've the following bean:

```
@Bean(name="dataSourceFoo")
public DataSource dataSourceFoo() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    ...
    return dataSource;
}
```

In my Bar @Configuration file I've the following bean:

```
@Bean(name="dataSourceBar")
public DataSource dataSourceBar() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    ...
    return dataSource;
}
```

In a third project, my test file looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ThirdProjectAppContextConfig.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetups({
        @DatabaseSetup(connection = "dataSourceFoo", value = "classpath:db/FooTest.xml"),
        @DatabaseSetup(connection = "dataSourceBar", value = "classpath:db/BarTest.xml") })
@TestPropertySource("/application.properties")
@DirtiesContext
@Transactional
public class FooBarTest {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        service.callFooBar();
        ...
    }
}
```

When I run the test it throws the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a DB Unit database connection, missing one the following beans: [dbUnitDatabaseConnection, dataSource]
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.getDatabaseConnectionUsingCommonBeanNames(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:141)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:112)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:278)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Anyone knows why isn't DBunit finding the connections?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DbUnitTestContextAdapter)` is looking for database configurations and the ones I defined are not found and dbunit uses "`dataSource`" by default. Placing the following configuration on test class will solve the problem:

```
@DbUnitConfiguration(databaseConnection={"dataSourceFoo","dataSourceBar"})
```

more info at [Spring Test DBUnit](http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/)